# Laravel + Inertia: unable to implement server side rendering with default scaffolding for Laravel Breeze

Tags: laravel, server-side-rendering, vite, inertiajs

On a fresh Laravel installation with `laravel/breeze` I was unable to implement SSR even with default scaffolding from Laravel docs.

I'm [running](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#server-side-rendering) `php artisan breeze:install vue --ssr`, it scaffolds everything and build assets with no errors. But when I check source code in browser I see no server-side rendered content (just `div` with `app` id)

Content is default (generated by `breeze:install --ssr` command) one, I've added nothing:

```js
// vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    ssr: {
        noExternal: ['@inertiajs/server'],
    },
});
```

```js
// app.js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

```js
// ssr.js
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue';
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import createServer from '@inertiajs/server';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

createServer((page) =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
        setup({ app, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
                .use(plugin)
                .use(ZiggyVue, {
                    ...page.props.ziggy,
                    location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.location),
                });
        },
    })
);
```

```html
// app.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>

        @routes
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>
```

Build script is `vite build && vite build --ssr`

Comment: got a same problem.. is there any solution?

Comment: @Tebe It is but I don't remember it to be honest. It was something on my side, something really stupid which I didn't even mentioned in the question. Cannot delete question as it has answers (I upvoted both of them, thanks guys)

Answer (score 3):

I think at some point Ziggy changed the object structure or something like this. Faced the same problem and managed to fix it by changing:

```
location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.location),
```

to

```
location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.url),
```

If you console.log(page.props.ziggy) right before the method you will see that there is a url key instead of location. I assume that they serve the same purpose.

Comment: I just dealt with this today myself. Wished I had found your answer a couple of hours earlier.

Answer (score 2):

When you SSR Laravel Inertia app you won't get full html in view page option. It is nothing wrong with it. To check if your site render correctly try to turn off js and then check the results. If it doesn't work you need to do 2 more things.

1. Install node.js or check if it has been installed. You need version 16 or above, couse inertia SSR use node.js under the hood.
2. You need to use artisan command to start SSR rendering:

> PHP artisan inertia:start-ssr

Then you will get SSR webpage on your backend port (usually:8000).

In production you must install node.js on your server and give artisan command as background process. If you use shared server, check if they have an option to install node.js. Then install process manager (for ex. pm2). Then you must start the SSR server in node.js env as a background process.